# Does SQLite leak memory with the SQLCipher extension?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm using [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) to store an encrypted [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. However, when I use `sqlite3_key` to encrypt the database, I start getting a memory leak. Observe the following sample:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>    

int main()
{
    sqlite3 * connection;
    sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &connection, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    sqlite3_key(connection, "passphrase", 10);
    sqlite3_close(connection);
}
```

This sample produces a memory leak. If I remove the call to `sqlite3_key`, the memory leak disappears.

I've narrowed down some possible culprits:

- Although the sample uses an in-memory database (hence `":memory:"`), I see the same result when using file-based databases.
- All of the return codes from the `sqlite3_*` calls are `SQLITE_OK`, meaning there aren't any errors.
- The buffer length of `10` for `"passphrase"` is not the problem.

However, no matter how many connections I create or how many different encryption keys I use, the memory leak is always about 8 kilobytes. This leads me to suspect that this is not actually a memory leak, but just some constant global memory in SQLite/SQLCipher that doesn't get freed manually.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a way to get rid of the leak? Even if this is not an official memory leak, it's hard to detect real memory leaks with this present.

I'm using a [SQLCipher library for Windows](https://github.com/CovenantEyes/sqlcipher-windows).

Comment: How are you detecting memory leaks? _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()?

Comment: Yes, within the Boost unit test framework.

Comment: No issues with the above code on Linux running the latest repo code.

Comment: @netcoder, how did you check for memory leaks?

Comment: Its worth noting that SQLCipher also has an test suite that we run before each release that checks for memory leaks on all operations, and it is showing no leaks with the current code base. IIRC, _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is somewhat notorious for erroneously reporting leaks that aren't really leaks.

Comment: @StephenLombardo : On my Ubuntu machine it leaks too, i'm using valgrind to check memory leak (I use the same code as above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked into this a bit further, and these reported leaks are a result of memory allocated by OpenSSL. Since SQLCipher doesn't know when the app is strictly done using it, `EVP_cleanup()` is not called, and the memory is reported by valgrind as a leak. We're working towards a simple fix that will try to identify when the OpenSSL structures are no longer in use by SQLCipher with some simple reference counting, so `EVP_cleanup()` can be called automatically.

As a quick workaround for this before the next release of SQLCipher, you could call `EVP_cleanup()` manually in the program before exiting.